# How to cache complex calulations in a wicket web application

Tags: java, caching, wicket

I am building a wicket web application. It shows a list of 'entities' with a `DataView` and also displaying a details page which works fine. Only the needed rows from the database are loaded into my `DataView`, so performance is good.

I can also show a calculated value on the details page, which is generated on the fly from the 'entity'. But when i want to sum up this calculated value on my list page, performance gets poor when there are several hundreds of rows in the table. This is because the value is generated for the whole table for every session.

Should i cache this calculated value (if yes, how can i do this) or would it be better to add a column in my database table that holds this value, which would violate the DRY principle?

Comment: With no code on show, my answer will be somewhat vague, but the answer in one word is: models.

Comment: But will the model be cached across sessions?

Comment: You mean, shared between different HTTP sessions? No, definitely not. So basically you need a way to cache things on an application level?

Comment: and where/how should this cache be attached? are there any frameworks?

Comment: As a starting point I'd say it should be attached to your application instance, if your cache is relatively simple and small, just add a field to your application class and cache the values there.

Comment: If this is about being expensive because the whole table is used instead of a subset (not exactly sure), you could try to calculate the sum based on your `ListDataProvider` and its `getIterator`method.

Comment: @Nicktar will the `ListDataProvider` Cache the result?

Comment: No, but you could reduce the number of rows taken into consideration to just the rows shown on the current page. If this isn't the intended result, you'll need to cache the result of your calculation as biziclop said...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @biziclop commented, a solution for a simple cache is adding a field to the Application Class, which caches the calculated value. This way, the calculations must be made on application startup and on every change of relevant data.